# Investigate convergence with cos/sin

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Well I want to investigate the convergence of the following integrals(in the linked picture):
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\cos(x^t)dx\quad,\quad t\in \mathbb{R}$$
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\sin(x^t)dx\quad,\quad t\in \mathbb{R}$$

for example , $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\cos\sqrt[4]{x^3}\,dx$$

Can someone throw a bone to how do I deal with this kind of problems?

Comment: Those integrals, in general, cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to do this, but do you think tailor expansions might help?

Answer (score 1):

Enforcing the substitution $x\to x^{1/t}$, we have

$$\int_1^\infty \cos(x^t)\,dx=\frac1t\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^{1-1/t}}\,dx$$

which converges provided $t>1$ using the [Dirichlet Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals).